# Django ORM aggregate tax sum

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a Django project. There are Store model and Analytics model.
I want to calculate taxes sum for each store.
Is it possible to aggregate it by Django ORM in one request to DB? Without any loop by stores list?

I don't want smth like this:

```
for store in stores:
    taxes_sum = store.sales_sum*store.tax/100
```

I want smth like this:

```
taxes_sum = StoreAnalytics.objects.filter(store__user=self.request.user).aggregate(
            sales_sum=Sum(F("accruals_sum"))*Sum(F("tax"))/100)
```

but each store has its own tax percent (6%, 15%, 20%....)

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default="", verbose_name="Name")
```

```
class StoreAnalytics(models.Model):

    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="store_id")
    sales_sum = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0), verbose_name="Sales")
    tax = models.IntegerField(
        default=6, validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)], verbose_name="Tax %"
    )
```

Is there any methods to calculate taxes sum?

Comment: can `StoreAnalytics` have multiple instances with the same `store_id`? and if you want total tax with the group by of `store` then you will have query set instead of aggregated result.
you can try this for queryset.
`StoreAnalytics.objects.filter(handle_as_per_your_requirement).values("store_id").annotate(total_tax=Sum("tax"))`

Comment: > can StoreAnalytics have multiple instances with the same store_id?   No, it can't. Eacj Store has only 1 StoreAnalytics instance.

Comment: For example: a User has 2 Stores. Store #1 has "sales_sum" = 1000 and "tax" = 5. Store #2 has "sales_sum" = 2000 and "tax" = 10. I want to calculate general taxes sum for a User. "taxes_sum" = (1000*5/100)+(2000*10/100). Can I get it by one ORM expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import (F, Sum)

StoreAnalytics.objects.filter().values("store__user_id").annotate(
                    total_value=Sum((F("sales_sum")*F("tax"))/100),
                ).order_by("store__user_id")
```